# Cannot apply masterpage to sub-sites

Tags: branding, sub-site

I can't seem to apply a masterpage (which has sub-site-specific branding) to only a **single** subsite.

If I try to 'Change the Look' of a site by applying a masterpage, I can only do it at the Parent-Site level instead of just the single subsite.

I notice that when I go to **Site Settings** > **Change the Look** > **Design Manager** > **Publish & Apply Design** I am redirected to Design Manager at the Parent Site Level.

What am I doing wrong?

If this is not possible, what are my options of having a one-pager with custom branding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok! I just found out what was wrong - I had not set Publishing Features on completely on parent site. Once I did that, I set publishing features on in the subsite and then suddenly a **Master Page** option popped up in my Subsite's **Look and Feel** section in its Site Settings!